# Get ID of item selected in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq

I have a `ComboBox` that gets filled with items from my database. I'm trying to get the `ID` of the item that is selected in the `ComboBox`, but nothing I've tried seems to be working.

```
int id = cbbilar.SelectedIndex + 1;
```

This is how I have it right now, it's very inefficient and stops working if the first items in the database are removed

```
var cars = (from z in db.Bilar 
            select new { Value = z.Id, Names = z.Marke.Namn + " "  + z.Namn }).ToList();
cbbilar.DataSource = cars;
cbbilar.DisplayMember = "Names";
cbbilar.ValueMember = "Value";
cbbilar.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This is the code for my `Combobox`. How do I make it fetch the `ID` of the `SelectedItem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `SelectedValue` and [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Like this:

```
int id;
bool result = int.TryParse(cbbilar.SelectedValue.ToString(), out id);
```

Comment: Can you not just cast SelectedValue directly to int as it passed in as int?

Comment: @IanofOz The `SelectedValue` is of type `object`.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! Thanks a lot! How come I had to write it this way instead of just simply `int id =   int.Parse(cbbilar.SelectedValue.ToString());` ?

Comment: @MattJ Check here to know more about `int.TryParse` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx I also included the link to MSDN in  my answer.

Comment: @S.Akbari True, but given the SelectedValue object holds an int, you should be able to cast it back to an int. I just double checked - create a new object, assign it an int value and you can cast it to an int. Obviously relies on knowing you pass an int in initially.Matt, you choice if you want to try that

Comment: In terms of Parse vs TryParse, all TryParse gives you is better error handling (ie a false return rather than an exception in the case of bad data). But if the data is good, they're the same. So is it possible your code for doing this conversion is happening perhaps before anything is selected?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got done:

```js
comboBoxPickupLoc.DataSource = pickupLocationRepo.GetPickupLocations();
comboBoxPickupLoc.DisplayMember = "LocationName";
comboBoxPickupLoc.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBoxPickupLoc.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

and then you can get the Id value as shown below

```js
  object value = comboBoxPickupLoc.SelectedValue;
  MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When ever I am grabbing the `SelectedIndex` value, I am doing so to place the `id` into another `DataBase` for various reasons.  I have used the TryParse to do this task but the line below is about as simple as it gets by pulling it as a string rather than parcing to an int.

```
string id = combobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get ID of item selected in WPF ComboBox

Country & State are your model classes.

code =>

```
Country country_selected = (Country)DDCountry.SelectedValue;  
State state_selected = (State)DDState.SelectedValue;  
int country_id = country_selected.country_id;
int state_id = state_selected.state_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but here is another way to take information form the db to the comboBox.

```
   private void userControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      scon.Open(); //--DB Connection
      string query = "SELECT * FROM AssetTypes"; //Query

      SqlDataReader row;
      SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(query,scon);
      row = scmd.ExecuteReader();

      if (row.HasRows)
      {
         while (row.Read())
         {
            AssetTypeComboBox.Items.Add(row["AssetTypesName"].ToString());
         }
      }
      scon.Close();
   }
```

to get the ID:

```
int itemID = AssetTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex + 1; //returns the ID number in the DB. provided the ;list was not sorted.
```

worked like a charm for me, maybe it can help others in future if they are struggling and do not understand much.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. They know how to populate a combobox. The question is how to get an object's ID value from it. You don't even mention that, let alone show how it's done.

Comment: @GertArnold , Hi , my apologies you are actually correct.  i will edit it and amend it to return the actual ID as in the DB .

Comment: SelectedIndex is *not* an object's ID value. This answer doesn't hold water.