# System.InvalidCastException in C# Visual Studio2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

I was trying to get IDs of combobox items in order to store them in the code and use them to replace labels whenever combobox selected items are changed. However, i encountered this error. I used the first var testID to get the IDs of cbx items. then inserted it into my getbyid method and converted it into INT. IT is actually an object. So when I debugged it, it crashed. So is there any way to solve this problem?

```
var testID = cbxTakeTest.SelectedValue;
var Test = new TestManager().GetById(Convert.ToInt32(testID));

               lblTakeTestQuestion1.Text = Test.Q1;
               lblTakeTestQuestion2.Text = Test.Q2;
               lblTakeTestQuestion3.Text = Test.Q3;
```

Value member was chosen as ID in the table where test names are stored

Comment: Stop converting it to int. If *IT is actually an object*, then it's not an int and shouldn't be converted to one.

Comment: what did you put in the combo box ?

Comment: Any other way to get int from Combobox? My method getByID works only with int

Comment: I put there test names from database. I needed to get their IDs from combobox in order to make all labels change according to selected item in Combobox

Comment: Show the code that loads teh combo

Comment: public void LoadTests()
        {
            cbxTakeTest.DataSource = new TestManager().GetAll();
            
        }

Comment: Then I inserted LoadTests() into the public form

Comment: Show the ValueMember setting. Show the definition of the property the ValueMember refers to. Edit them into your question; do not post code in comments

Comment: Is there any other way to get selected value`s id from combobox in INT form so that there will be no need to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was already answered here:
[Get ID of item selected in ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303980/get-id-of-item-selected-in-combobox)

In short just apply ToString() to your testID.